# How to delete results returned from Views UI

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-hooks

I am getting results as expected using Views UI. But I don't want to display a particular record from the output of Views UI> How to achieve this and will I require any hooks for this?

Ex. My Views return result as 1,2,3,4. Now I don't want to show 1 in the result. I cannot change the query using hook_views_query_alter as 1 is being used in "where" clause.

Answer (score 0):

Implement [hook_views_query_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7) by adding a condition that excludes the record that you do not want in the result set.

Comment: No I cant do so because my scenario is like that:- User for example comes to node A page. Now B,C,D are three nodes that is being related with A. When I want to show all the nodes related to A then the view displayed A,B,C,D which is correct as well. Now I don't want user to display A node inside view in A node page. So I have to remove A node from view result. Also I cant change the query because where clause of my query will be "ContentID"="A".

Comment: What do you mean by *query will be "ContentID"="A"*? I thought you query is already there, except for the part where A is excluded from the results.

Comment: How did you do the *related with A* part?

Comment: Actually A has one Node Reference field called Subject which is another content type. Suppose Subjects are Physics,Maths,Biology,Chemistry. Now the relations of subject and teachers A,B,C,D,E are as follows: - A teach Physics,Maths,Biology. B Teach Physics,Biology, C Teach Chemistry,Physics, D Teach Maths Biology, E Teach Chemistry.User comes to visit Teacher A .Now I want to display all the teacher who teach the subjects like A. So in my case B,C,D will be filtered because they have one or more subjects in common with A. But Teacher E will be discarded as the subject is not common with A.

Comment: In this scenario I need to give "ContentID"="A" in where condition and I don't want to display A again in the view. So the view will show B,C,D instead of A,B,C,D. I hope I am clear with my requirement. Please help me in achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
function hook_views_pre_render(&$view) {

  if($view->name=="ViewName") {  


if($view->current_display=='Display') {

  unset($view->result[1]);

}
  }
}
```